# Can Only Write Char* to LPVOID buffer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

So, I have a File Mapping Object (it's 64KB), and a View of that mapping (it's also 64KB at offset 0).

When I write to the view, I first write the length of the data to be written, then I write the data (so that I can read the data by first reading the length, then reading that number of bytes)

For some reason, this code only works when writing to offsets before 16KB (using an offset of 16383 works, 16384 I get a memory violation).

Here is the code:

```
LIB_EXPORT bool mem_write_to_view(mem_mapview_p view, DWORD offset, unsigned char *bytes, int len)
{
    __try
    {
        ((LPDWORD)(view->data))[offset] = len; // access violation only on this line; if I remove this line, it will write all the way up to 64KB
        int sizeOfLen = sizeof(DWORD) / sizeof(char);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            ((char *)(view->data))[i + offset + sizeOfLen] = bytes[i];
        }
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION)
    {
        printf("ERROR: error\r\n");
        report_last(view->reporter, "mem_write_to_view");
        report_last_explicit(view->reporter, "mem_write_to_view", "Failed to write to view.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As the comment in the code indicates, I only get an access violation when I try to set the length (after 16KB, again, this works before 16KB, I'm not sure why), otherwise, I can use this method to write all the way up to the end of a map view (hence the title of this question "Can only write char* to LPVOID buffer")

`view->data` is initialized with this line:
`view->data = MapViewOfFile(map->hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, offset_hi, offset_lo, size);` before a call to `mem_write_to_view` is made.

Any idea why this would occur (And also more specifically why it only occurs at offsets of 16KB+)?

I ran a `VirtualQuery` on the LPVOID pointer returned by `MapViewOfFile` and confirmed it is indeed 64KB in size.

I really don't know much at all about low-level memory access (I come from a mostly high-level object oriented background) so I have no clue what problems I may cause by interpreting `LPVOID` as `LPDWORD` and then interpreting it as a `char *` but I'm pretty sure this is the only way to write the length in front of the data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DWORD` is 4 bytes, and an `LPDWORD` is a pointer to DWORDs, so pointer arithmentic on it is scaled by 4.  So when you do:

```
((LPDWORD)(view->data))[offset] = len;
```

it scales (multiplies) the offset by 4 to get the byte address to write to.  Which means that when offset is 16384, it writes 64KB into the block -- which is just past the end.

What you probably want it

```
*(LPDWORD)((char *)view->data + offset) = len;
```

in order to make the offset be measured in bytes (unscaled).

Comment: Ohhhhh duh... Makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: Couldn't I also just divide offset by 4 (or `sizeof(DWORD)`)

Comment: You could, as long as offset is always a mulitple of 4.  You might want to require that anyway for alignment reasons (x86 allows unaliagned access but it is less efficient than aligned)

Comment: Well I'm wanting 8 8KB subsections/"pages" per view so that should be fine. Thanks again!